# How do I concatenate a variable and an array?

Tags: java

Is it possible to concatenate a variable with an array? For example:

```
System.out.print(Array"+"i"+"[k]);// this is nt getting
```

so that it should become like this System.out.print(Array1[k]); "if i=1" after using some loop iteration.

Comment: No.  Java has no facilities for that sort of thing.  At best you can make your "ArrayN" variables be instance variables and use reflections, but that's a lot of effort vs just doing what you should have in the first place and used an array.

Comment: So you want to print out a value only if i==1?

Comment: yes with Array..[k]. ".." means I want here "i" value

Comment: Maybe you should give an example of what output your are looking for because this is still pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the concept of Array instead of concatenating the variables.
In your case, it should be as following:

```
String[][] foo = new String[10][10];
System.out.println(foo[0][k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is a two-dimensional array, which is just an array of arrays.

```
String[][] arr = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"x", "y", "z"}};
System.out.println(arr[1][2]); //prints "z"
```